# How to pipe password to perforce p4 login command for automate login?

Tags: window, perforce

I need to know how do I pass password when perforce p4 login is executed from powershell. When p4 login is executed there comes enter password: field due to which I can't automate the login step. I need to pipe the password with p4 login command so that this can be automated. Please suggest how to do that. I did tried as "p4 -u user -P password login " but did not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, pipe the password to the login command:

```
echo password|p4 -u user login
```

`p4 login` doesn't read the plaintext password from `P4PASSWD` (or the equivalent `-P` flag) because having your cleartext password in your environment or in a file is a security liability (anyone able to read that file is now able to login as you from anywhere) and is therefore discouraged.

Speaking of which, putting the password in your script to automate `p4 login` is discouraged for similar reasons.  :)  The recommended way of doing this is to require the user to login prior to running the script (a default login lasts for 12 hours so if you're running a bunch of scripts you still only need to login once a day).

If the script is part of a fully automated job where you can't have a human user enter the password every day, the recommended strategy is then to give the automation user a non-expiring ticket (bound to that IP) and hardcode THAT in the script.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell you can use this snippet:

```
p4 set P4USER=$user
$password | p4 login
```

Note:
`p4 set P4PASSWD=...`
Does NOT work.

Answer (score -1):

In windows cmd, you can use this:
powershell -command "echo "Password" | p4 login"